# Are there a specification of an API or samples for the DX tool for Android!

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, dx

I'd like to use DX Tool API for triying to generate ad-hoc a dexfile invoking this library. Are there any sample or any specification of this library?

Thanks for all

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You could try what [the official tool page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#dx) suggests.

> dx --help

Comment: My problem is that I want to use this library at runtime, so I need to know its API.